# Broken geometry

Tags: modeling

How to solve the issue? Looks like an area exists within the edge
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image that shows the object in edit mode, so that the topology is visible.

Comment: maybe even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question entirely, but from looking at your image I would try getting rid of duplicate vertices, then recalculating normals if that doesn't solve it.

To do this tab into edit mode, double tap the <kbd>A</kbd> key to select all vertices, then press the <kbd>M</kbd> key to merge and select *by distance* if there are still problems with all vertices selected press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.